# Google analytics results differ between iframe and parent

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, statistics, tracking

We are having trouble with analytics results not matching up between the parent page and iframe child. We're aware that tracking shouldn't be about solid numbers, but our differences are too big to ignore.

Our setup is like this:

We run a e-store, lets say **estore.com**, tracking here works as expected and we've never had issues.

Recently we implemented a "nested" store for a partner, here is where the trouble begins. On the parent page of our partner where we **can't** control the scripts or adjust anything. This parent page implements TWO iframe children.

The first iframe is ours, the iframe itself works perfectly and contains a part of our Magento store, no code or script errors and it implements a default analytics script. The iframe runs on **partner.estore.com** on our end.

The second iframe is a verification test the partner added later, its on its own entirely unique domain and is pretty much just a empty page with an analytics script in it.

The tracking between the parent and the second iframe matches up with minimal differences (less then 1% or so) while the tracking between the parent and the first iframe (ours) tends to differ between 40% and 60% in the final result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this document: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Though it's very out of date, there's a section "Configuring iFrame Tracking for Internet Explorer," which basically explains that due to cross-domain security measures implemented in browsers, iframes hosted on different domains than the parent window cannot generally set cookies (which are required for GA to function correctly). You used to be able to get around this by setting P3P headers for IE7, etc. and Firefox just allowed you to do it.

Now, as of May 2013, most browsers, including Safari, Chrome, and, soon, Firefox, do not allow iframes to set cookies across domains regardless of P3P headers and various other tricks.